# store test kit do not appear in my Project menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am testing Windows Phone App 8.1 with Visual Studio 2013. I found out that the option Store Test Kit does not appear in the menú.

I have download a code example from https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-23-Testing-and-Submitting-to-the-Store and it appear in that example.

What i am missing? I need to register my App?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The video was done with vs2012, which has that nice Store Test interface with drag and drop features. I don't think that is available in vs2013 ultimate (the version that I am using). However, Run Project > Store > Launch Windows Phone App Certification Test.

NB: You may not run the test if you have not yet installed the certification kit, which is available here: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/app-certification-kit

If the test succeeds you can go ahead and publish the app.

If it fails then you will get a nice report telling you exactly why it failed. You will then need to sort them out manually one at a time. Build your application every time after correction and run the test until it succeeds.

That is what I did.